# Django - Make two separate queries, combine the results, then eliminate duplicates

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is there a fast and easy way to do this? I haven't been able to find anything that's already out there that seems to do this already.

Since it's a queryset, i don't think i can use the unique properties of Set to solve the problem either.  any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108193/union-and-intersect-in-django

Answer (score 4):

Use Q objects, one for each query, and OR them together. Then, use `distinc()`

```
qs = SomeModel.objects.get(Q(some_attribute=something) |
                           Q(some_other_attribute=something)).distinct()
```

Comment: interesting, thanks! unfortunately i'm using a backend that doesn't support the "OR" keyword, so it can't execute this as one query statement, but two completely separate ones.  I haven't been able to figure out a way to use the distinct on two completely separate queries

Comment: Well, if you don't need a queryset in return, you could just do results = set(list(qs1) + list(qs2)).