# How can I find the union of two Django querysets?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I’ve got a Django model with two custom manager methods. Each returns a different subset of the model’s objects, based on a different property of the object.

Is there any way to get a queryset, or just a list of objects, that’s the union of the querysets returned by each manager method?

Comment: (From a deleted answer) See this question for a variation that works with QuerySets from different Models: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view

Comment: Starting from version 1.11, django query sets have a builtin union method. I have added it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 223, accepted):

This works and looks a bit cleaner:

```
records = query1 | query2
```

If you don't want duplicates, then you will need to append `.distinct()`:

```
records = (query1 | query2).distinct()
```

Comment: While the accepted answer returns a union iterable (list to be exact), like OP has asked, this method returns a true union of querysets. This queryset can be operated on further, which is desired in many circumstances.

Comment: Due to a Django bug, this construction can sometimes return incorrect results when dealing with `ManyToManyField`s. For example, you will sometimes see that `records.count()` will be greater than `query1.count() + query2.count()`, which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: @Jian can you clarify django version with the bug and a link to the djangoproject issue?

Comment: @IMFletcher: I have 1.4.5 and  all = my_instance.forward_many_to_many.all() | my_instance.reverse_many_to_many.all() ; all has duplicate entry where I thought `union` should eliminate the duplciate.

Comment: records = query1 | query2 ; records = records.distinct() would give me the correct result

Comment: how does this work? we know '|' is bitwise OR. So how does Query1 | Query2 work? Does it take a bit representation of query1 and query2?

Comment: You can overload operators in Python. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html. So what Django does is create special methods for the QuerySet object. See the code here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L178 the `QuerySet` class provides methods for `__and__` and `__or__` that are called when the `&` or `|` operators are used between two `QuerySet` objects (also used for the `Q` class as well).

Comment: Does this union respect the original order of the querysets? if I do `final_query = query1 | query2` will final_query be a queryset with the elements of query1 first and followed by the elements of query2 (that are not in query1)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't expect it to respect the existing order. However, you can call `order_by` on `final_query` afterwards. If it is vital that each part keep its existing order, then you should combine them manually.

Comment: I think that comment from @JordanReiter deserves more votes. It is important to understand that the ORM will create an OR query not a UNION query so that method cannot be used to achieve custom ordering.

Comment: @eugene's comment about needing to call `queryset.distinct()` to get distinct results should be added to the answer.  I had a bug where results weren't distinct, so this needed to be called.

Comment: this is not in django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/), is it deprecated?

Comment: @mehmet no clue why it isn't in the docs. It still works in Django 1.10 as far as I know. Here's the direct link to the source that implements it: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L298

Comment: @Quazer This is technically true, but in most cases the output will match the desired outcome, which is a combination of all records that match the conditions in query 1 with the records that match the conditions in query 2. `select ... from tt where name='foo' or name='goo'` is similar output to `select .. from tt where name='foo' union select ... from tt where name='goo'`.

Answer (score 70):

Starting from [version 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#union), django querysets have a builtin union method.

```
q = q1.union(q2) #q will contain all unique records of q1 + q2
q = q1.union(q2, all=True) #q will contain all records of q1 + q2 including duplicates
q = q1.union(q2,q3) # more than 2 queryset union
```

See my [blog post](https://technowhisp.com/django-orm-union-intersection-and-difference/) on this for more examples.

Comment: I couldn't get all=True to work. Ended up doing casting my queryset to a set before returning it to the client.

Comment: @BradenHolt, all=True, means it will contain duplicate records. You can simply remove all=True to avoid casting it to a set.

Comment: after this doesnt work DjangoFilterBackend, how i can use union and DjangoFilterBackend ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work for models with a default ordering defined in the model's Meta. Whenever I try to combine these with .union, I receive the following error: "ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements."

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest using 'query1.union(query2)' instead of 'query1 | query2';
I got different results from the above two methods and the former one is what I expected.
The following is what I had come across:

```
print "union result:"
for element in query_set1.union(query_set2):
    print element

print "| result:"
for element in (query_set1 | query_set2):
    print element
```

result:

```
union result:
KafkaTopic object
KafkaTopic object
KafkaTopic object
KafkaTopic object
KafkaTopic object

| result:
KafkaTopic object
KafkaTopic object
```