# How to append multiple filter() queries into one variable

Tags: python, django

If I have three different queries of a model how do i append them into one variable

```
x = AnswerModel.objects.filter(user= 'tim')

y = AnswerModel.objects.filter(user= 'paul')

z = AnswerModel.objects.filter(question= 'i like jam')

x = x.append(y)
x = x.append(z)
```

Comment: You can append them in a tuple. _x.append((y,z))_

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find the union of two Django querysets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411049/how-can-i-find-the-union-of-two-django-querysets)

Comment: Looks like you want to [chain them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/796381/846892).

Comment: i dont want to combine them inside a filter query of a model, i need to do it using two variable x append y  i plan to do it in a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `chain`.

```
from itertools import chain
x = list(chain(x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `|`:

```
x = AnswerModel.objects.filter(user= 'tim')
y = AnswerModel.objects.filter(user= 'paul')
z = AnswerModel.objects.filter(question= 'i like jam')

qs = x | y | z
```

Or, using `django.db.models.Q`:

```
x = AnswerModel.objects.filter(Q(user='tim') | Q(user='paul') | Q(question='i like jam')
```

Both methods will return all results from all querysets in a single queryset.