# Merge and sum counts of two annotate django

Tags: django

I have the following two QuerySets

```
movies_actor=[<Movie: DJango>, <Movie: Paloma de papel>, <Movie: Asu Mare: la película>, <Movie: Mariposa negra>, <Movie: Mañana te cuento>, <Movie: No se lo digas a nadie>]

movies_genres=[<Movie: Dias de Santiago>, <Movie: Ciudad M>, <Movie: DJango>, <Movie: Mariposa negra>, <Movie: No se lo digas a nadie>, <Movie: La Gran Sangre: La Pelicula>, <Movie: La Ciudad y Los Perros>, <Movie: Paloma de papel>]
```

Each element of the two query sets has the attribute counter. For example movie_actor[0].counter=2. I need to merge and sum this atributte in another QuerySet. Could you help me to obtain that please?

Comment: what do you mean by merge? Can you be little more clear? An example would really help

Comment: Seems like you could try this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4412293/1816414

Answer (score 0):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411049/how-can-i-find-the-union-of-two-django-querysets/4412293#4412293) you could first merge your querysets:

```
    merged_queryset = movies_actor | movies_genres
```

and then do the aggregation:

```
    total = merged_queryset.agggregate(Sum('counter'))
```

I have tried it with similar models on **Django 1.8** and it works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
sum_movies_actor = movies_actor.aggregate(Sum('counter'))
sum_movies = movies.aggregate(Sum('counter'))
total = sum_movies_actor['counter__sum'] + sum_movies['counter__sum']
```