# Union of two Django querysets not working

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-2.1

Django Union **always worked** but i got a **strange** situation where its not work properly.

I have tried to get union of some queryset but got *strange* result.

I have also check with [How can I find the union of two Django querysets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411049/how-can-i-find-the-union-of-two-django-querysets) but its not working as well.

Here i have attached image to show my tries.

[image]

in the above image i get four queryset( qs, qs1 , qs2, my_qs ) after **filter BetDetails model**
here i want to get result in my_qs
And when i tried to merge/Union of the queryset got on blank queryset in my_qs  **While i have data in qs1** . 
expected result should be

```
  <QuerySet [<BetDeetails: BetDetails object (29)>]>
```

But i got :

```
   <QuerySet []>
```

model:

```
class BetDetails(DefaultFieldsModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I don't know why its showing this type of result.
Can anyone please explain and guide me to get desired result.

Comment: Do the `qs` query the same model?

Comment: Yes, i am getting all querysets after filter BetDetails model.

Comment: Please provide the models for the querysets, and see [*Why should I provide a minimal, reproducible example for a very simple sql query?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @CalebGoodman question is updated with model details.

Comment: is `DefaultFieldsModel` a third party package?  I am not familiar with it.  Also, what model are you trying to Union with?

Comment: @CalebGoodman No, its is simple model created by me where i added some defaluts model field like created date, updated date , status etc. 
and i am trying to union BetDetails model's queryset.