How to Make Django Model Choice Field Accept Multiple Criteria
With a model defined as such
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) # intended to be left as NOT unique

I would like to pick a product by either its code or its name. For example, if Product 1's code is SUS304 and name Stainless Steel 304, type SUS304 or Stainless Steel 304 in the form should both select this product.
I try to use a union queryset as source queryset, but Django complains that .filter after .union is not supported.
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    codes = Product.objects.annotate(full=F('code'))
    names = Product.objects.annotate(full=F('name'))
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(codes.union(names), to_field_name='full')
    class Meta:
        # Order is another model that have a ForeignKey to Product
        model = Order
        fields = ['product']

How can I achieve this (especially in Django's way)?
PS1. It is possible that multiple products share the same name, or one product's name is another's code. In such case, I would expect a ValidationError.
PS2. Despite the length limit, there is no effective way to determine if a given string is a code or a name. SUS304 could also be a product's name.

What about overriding  label_from_instance to get customized model display labels in your customized ModelChoiceField? (Doc here)
Based on this:
class ProductModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.code} ({obj.name})"

In a queryset, where you want to filter based on two or more fields with OR logic, you use Q(keyword=value) | Q(otherkeyword=othervalue). (Q objects). In the context of a ModelChoiceField, this would be used to restrict the range of objects from which the user can choose. Nothing to do with what the label on the choice is.
Maybe I didn't fully understand the question.

I still want to put code and name into different options. But yes I can take advantage of the Q object and  validate it by my self. Thanks for your suggestion.

Ah. I understand better now. I think you can get two choices referring to the same object with different labels by using label_from_instance by using a union of querysets like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411049/how-can-i-find-the-union-of-two-django-querysets where one of the queries annotates its objects and you check for the annotation on the object in label_from_instance. I've never done this. If you succeed, post it here as an answer!
