# Django Many To Many intersection filtering

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

For the sake of simplicity let's say I only have 2 models: Book, Author

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='100')
    ...

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='100')
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    ...
```

I want to filter Books using a list of authors. What I tried to do is:

```
authors = [...] # a list of author objects
Books.objects.filter(authors__in=authors)
```

But here, the authors will be ORed when I want them ANDed.
Is there any way to AND many-to-many filtering??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could & together a bunch of Q objects:

```
q = Q()
for author in authors:
    q &= Q(authors=author)
Books.objects.filter(q)
```

To exclude books that have authors outside the list, you could limit the query to books with exactly the number of authors in the list:

```
Books.objects.annotate(count=Count('authors')).filter(count=len(authors)).filter(q)
```

**Update:**

Based on comments, I think the requirement is to get all books authored by at least one author in the list, but exclude books with any authors outside the list.

So we build a queryset selecting the authors that we hate:

```
# this queryset will be embedded as a subquery in the next
bad_authors = Author.objects.exclude(name__in=['A1', 'A2'])
```

Then exclude them to find the books we want:

```
# get all books without any of the bad_authors
Books.objects.exclude(authors__in=bad_authors)
```

This will return all books except those authored by someone outside your list.  If you also want to exclude those with no authors listed, add another exclude call:

```
Books.objects.exclude(authors__in=bad_authors).exclude(authors=None)
```

This will leave us with just the books authored by one or more of the good ones!

Comment: One more thing: I want to be able to filter books that have authors from the list only, no extra authors. Could you help me with that plz?

Comment: @goliney Why is that the wrong thing to do? Please elaborate.

Comment: @dokkaebi I thought again, and now your approach seems to me more correct. +1

Comment: Thanx a lot @dokkaebi, that's great. But I think I was a bit unclear in my last question, so let me give you an example:
authors = ['A1','A2']

Comment: @CodePirate I think all this comment changes from your original post is that `authors` may not actually be a list of Author objects. Does the code I posted fail in some way?

Comment: I want books that are written by 'A1', 'A2' or both but no body else.

Comment: If the query I offered doesn't work, let me know what you get instead and how it differs from what you expected, and I'll take a look at it. If it's just an issue of a list of strings vs. Author objects, then you'll need `authors__name=author` in place of `authors=author`.

Comment: it's not just a string issue. Let's say we have: `authors = [A1,A2]`. The query you provided gets books that are written by both A1 and A2. I also want books that are written by only one of them.

Comment: Do you also have the requirement that books with an author outside your list are excluded? If not, your original query works, I think.

Comment: Yes, so a book written by A1 & A3 shouldn't be returned. I really appreciate your help and patience.